# How to backup images stored in the root directory of my app

Tags: android

In my app I capture images and store them in the app's root directory. These images can only be viewed through my app and will not be viewed in gallery. Now I need to backup these images like a db backup. How can I do that? Please help me.

This is the code to store images in the root folder:

```
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave) {
    File direct = new File(getFilesDir() + "/CAT_IMG/");
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String fileName = "fav" + timeStamp + ".JPG";
    if (!direct.exists()) {
       // File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/CAT_IMG");
        direct.mkdir();
    }

    File file = new File(direct, fileName);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is the code to backup db:

```
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String backupDBPath = String.format("%s.bak", DataProvider.DATABASE_NAME);

            String currentDBPath = "//data//" + getPackageName() + "//databases//" + databaseName + "";
            //   File currentDB = context.getDatabasePath(DataProvider.);
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);

            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup Successful!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What do you consider to be the root directory of your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code is saving a JPEG image to the app directory, and the second code is copying a database to a backup location. Copying a database file has nothing to do with backing up images.

You'd have to copy all your JPEG files to another location like this

```
public void backup() {
    File direct = new File(getFilesDir() + "/CAT_IMG/");
    File backupDirect = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/backup/CAT_IMG/");
    for(File srcFile : direct.listFiles()) {
        if (srcFile.isFile() && srcFile.getName().endsWith(".JPG")) {
           File targetFile = packupDirect.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + srcFile.getName();
           copyFile(srcFile, targetFile);
        }
    }
}

private void copyFile(File src, File dest) {
    FileChannel sourceChannel = null;
    FileChannel destChannel = null;
    try {
        sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
        destChannel = new FileOutputStream(dest).getChannel();
        destChannel.transferFrom(sourceChannel, 0, sourceChannel.size());
    } finally {
        sourceChannel.close();
        destChannel.close();
    }
}
```

I haven't tested that code but something like that should work.

But keep in mind that StackOverflow actually isn't a platform where you ask people to write your code.

Comment: Oops, should be `listFiles()` not `listFile()`. It enumerates all files that are in the given directory, so that you backup all the images and not just one.

Comment: If the IDE says "Cannot resolve" try to press Alt+Enter and select "Import class" in the menu that appears. This should add the necessary imports.

Comment: Sir...Help me import pictures in my db...How can i do that

Comment: Please open a new question for that. If you want you can send me the link in a comment here as well then I will answer you there, but you have to create a new question.